# up arrow, down arrow on a menu and hidden submenu

Tags: angular

I would like to create a menu with a down arrow like this:

[illustration - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B1fI.png)

When I click on `Market`, a submenu is shown, and the arrow is up.

[illustration - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8reFi.png)

I don't understand how to I can get this same result.

[my menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68y8S.png)

admin.component.html

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo-details">
    <i class="bx bxl-c-plus-plus"></i>
    <span class="logo_name">Menu</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === 'market' }">
      <a
        routerLink="market"
        (click)="selectElementMenu(); selectedTab = 'market'"
      >
        <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
        <span class="links_name">Market</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<section class="home-section">
  <nav>
    <div class="sidebar-button">
      <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn"></i>
      <span class="dashboard">Dashboard</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

admin.component.ts

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  elementMenu: boolean = false;
  selectedTab!: string;

  ngOnInit() {}

  selectElementMenu() {
    this.elementMenu = !this.elementMenu;
  }
}
```

The code is on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1sawka?file=src/app/admin/admin.component.ts)

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use *ngIf to conditionally render icon

```
<span class="links_name">Market</span>
<i class="bx bx-chevron-down" *ngIf="selectedTab != 'market'"></i>
<i class="bx bx-chevron-up" *ngIf="selectedTab == 'market'"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, Vijay's answer will work, but I'd rather do this

```
<i [class]="(selectedTab === 'market') ? 'bx bx-chevron-up' : 'bx bx-chevron-down'"></i>
```

I used a ternary operator for the class (present in most programming languages, if not all), it translates to :

```
if(selectedTab is equal to market) then 'bx bx-chevron-up' else 'bx bx-chevron-down'
```

There is no point in duplication elements for both cases when your whole need is to change an icon.

EDIT: If you need this for multiple elements (which I think you do since that looks like a `sidenav`, then you can do a function in the component that takes the classes and the value and then return the class accordingly :

```
chevron_position(class1: string, class2: string, value): string {
    return (selectedTab === value) ? class1 : class2;
}
```